# Discontinuous slice in python list

Tags: python, performance, list, slice

I'm looking for an efficient way of achieving this, which I think is a slicing-like operation:

```
>>> mylist = range(100)
>>>magicslicer(mylist, 10, 20)
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,60,61,62,63......,97,98,99]
```

the idea is: the slicing gets 10 elements, then *skips* 20 elements, then gets next 10, then skips next 20, and so on.

I think I should not use loops if possible, for the very reason to use slice is (I guess) to do the "extraction" efficiently in a single operation.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`itertools.compress` (new in 2.7/3.1) nicely supports use cases like this one, especially when combined with `itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle, compress
seq = range(100)
criteria = cycle([True]*10 + [False]*20) # Use whatever pattern you like
>>> list(compress(seq, criteria))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Python 2.7 timing (relative to Sven's explicit list comprehension):

```
$ ./python -m timeit -s "a = range(100)" "[x for start in range(0, len(a), 30) for x in a[start:start+10]]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.96 usec per loop

$ ./python -m timeit -s "from itertools import cycle, compress" -s "a = range(100)" -s "criteria = cycle([True]*10 + [False]*20)" "list(compress(a, criteria))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.76 usec per loop
```

Python 3.2 timing (also relative to Sven's explicit list comprehension):

```
$ ./python -m timeit -s "a = range(100)" "[x for start in range(0, len(a), 30) for x in a[start:start+10]]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.41 usec per loop

$ ./python -m timeit -s "from itertools import cycle, compress" -s "a = range(100)" -s "criteria = cycle([True]*10 + [False]*20)" "list(compress(a, criteria))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.78 usec per loop
```

As can be seen, it doesn't make a great deal of difference relative to the in-line list comprehension in 2.7, but helps significantly in 3.2 by avoiding the overhead of the implicit nested scope.

A similar difference can also be seen in 2.7 if the aim is to iterate over the resulting sequence rather than turn it into a fully realised list:

```
$ ./python -m timeit -s "a = range(100)" "for x in (x for start in range(0, len(a), 30) for x in a[start:start+10]): pass"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.82 usec per loop
$ ./python -m timeit -s "from itertools import cycle, compress" -s "a = range(100)" -s "criteria = cycle([True]*10 + [False]*20)" "for x in compress(a, criteria): pass"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.61 usec per loop
```

For especially long patterns, it is possible to replace the list in the pattern expression with an expression like `chain(repeat(True, 10), repeat(False, 20))` so that it never has to be fully created in memory.

Comment: Nice!  Note that the explicit list comprehension will still be faster if you are skipping a lot of values, since `compress()` has to iterate over all of them while the list comprehension really skips them.

Comment: True, although the converse benefit for the `compress()` approach is that it works with arbitrary iterables, even ones that don't support slicing.

Comment: Oh, my, I created a "monster question" :o)  This answer is very what-I-was-looking-for, since I heard the "C level" magic words. I will have to test it soon. Also, this nice way to use `python` straight from command line is new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe the best way is the straight-forward approach:

```
def magicslicer(seq, take, skip):
    return [x for start in range(0, len(seq), take + skip)
              for x in seq[start:start + take]]
```

I don't think you can avoid the loops.

**Edit**: Since this is tagged "performance", here a comparison with the modulo solution for `a = range(100)`:

```
In [2]: %timeit [x for start in range(0, len(a), 30)
                   for x in a[start:start + 10]]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.89 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit [e for i, e in enumerate(a) if i % 30 < 10]
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.8 us per loop
```

Comment: great! Now we also have a simple and useful example of `timeit` use! Thanks!

Comment: `itertools.compress` allows the looping to be pushed down to the C level, and is as fast as a list comprehension and faster than a generator expression in 2.7 and faster than both in 3.2 (due to the implicit nested scope in 3.x comprehensions).

Answer (score 4):

I think that slices cannot do it, unfortunately. I'd solve the problem using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> a = range(100)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
    ...
 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
>>> [e for i, e in enumerate(a) if i % 30 < 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are working with numbers only, but in case you are there is a faster way if you stick to numpy. But the following will only work if you have list that consists of sublists of equal length that were flattened out.

For comparison:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle, compress

startList = list(range(0, 3000))
startNpArray = np.linspace(0,2999,3000,dtype=np.int)

def WithNumpy(seq, keep, skip):
    return seq.reshape((-1, keep+skip))[:,:keep+1].flatten()

def WithItertools(seq, keep, skip):
    criteria = cycle([True]*keep + [False]* skip)
    return list(compress(seq, criteria))

%timeit WithNumpy(startListNp, 10, 20)
>>> 2.59 µs ± 48.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit WithItertools(startList, 10, 20)
>>> 33.5 µs ± 911 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: A masterful use of reshaping and slicing! Very enlightening!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def magicslicer(l, stepsize, stepgap):
    output = []
    i = 0
    while i<len(l):
        output += l[i:i+stepsize]
        i += stepsize + stepgap
    return output


mylist = range(100)
print magicslicer(mylist,10,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>[mylist[start:start+10] for start in mylist[::30]]
>>>[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39], [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69], [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]
```

but i obtain a list of list :(

Answer (score 0):

`[x for x in range(100) if x%30 < 10]` is another way to do it. But, this can be slow as the list size grows.

A function on the same lines

```
def magic_slice(n, no_elems, step):
    s = no_elems + step
    return [x for x in range(n) if x%s < no_elems]
```

Comment: The people suggesting list comprehensions are on the right track. You are correct that a loop is needed, but list comprehensions put the loop inside the Python engine where it is faster than an explicit loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = range(100)

otherlist = ['21','31','689','777','479','51','71','yut','poi','ger',
             '11','61','789','zozozozo','8888','1']



def magic_slicer(iterable,keep,throw):
        it = iter(iterable).next
        for n in xrange((len(iterable)//keep+throw)+1):
                for i in xrange(keep):  yield it()
                for i in xrange(throw):  it()

print list(magic_slicer(mylist,10,20))
print
print list(magic_slicer(otherlist,2,3))


print '__________________'


def magic_slicer2(iterable,keep,throw):
        return ( x for i,x in enumerate(iterable) if -1< i%(keep+throw)<keep) 

print list(magic_slicer2(mylist,10,20))
print
print list(magic_slicer2(otherlist,2,3))
```

result

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]

['21', '31', '51', '71', '11', '61', '1']
__________________
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]

['21', '31', '51', '71', '11', '61', '1']
```