# Index two sets of columns in an array

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to slice columns out of an array and assign to a new variable, like so.

```
array1 = array[:,[0,1,2,3,15,16,17,18,19,20]]
```

Is there a short cut for something like this?

I tried this, but it threw an error:

```
array1 = array[:,[0:3,15:20]]
```

This is probably really simple but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Are those arrays or lists? If they are numpy arrays, there are shortcuts like `numpy.r_`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.r_`:

> Translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(100).reshape(5, 20)
cols = np.r_[:3, 15:20]

print(arr[:, cols])
[[ 0  1  2 15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 55 56 57 58 59]
 [60 61 62 75 76 77 78 79]
 [80 81 82 95 96 97 98 99]]
```

At the end of the day, probably only a little less verbose than what you have now, but could come in handy for more complex cases.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `np.r_[:3, 15:20]`?

Answer (score 3):

For most simple cases like this, the best and most straightforward way is to use concatenation:

```
array1 = array[0:3] + array[15:20]
```

For more complicated cases, you'll need to use a custom slice, such as NumPy's `s_`, which allows for multiple slices with gaps, separated by commas. You can read about it [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html).

Also, if your slice follows a pattern (i.e. get 5, skip 10, get 5 etc), you can use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress), as explained by user [ncoghlan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597742/ncoghlan) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814136/7662085) answer.

Comment: Just as a warning, this works for *lists*, but numpy arrays will of course add or error if the sizes cannot be broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list(range(0, 4)) + list(range(15, 20))`