# C++ "for" loop condition in python

Tags: python, c++, loops, for-loop

Is there a one-line way to translate this "for" loop from C++ to python?

```
for(int i = 0; i < = 10 && i != 6; i++)
```

I mean in C++ we have :

```
for(initial_value; condition(s); step)
```

and I am looking for the analogue version in Python where we can impose one or several conditions.

Comment: Not clear what you want. In particular, the C++ code can be simplified: `for(int i = 0; i!= 6; i++)`

Comment: Unless `i` gets modified inside the loop?

Comment: @mch my bad, you are correct

Comment: Python's range function also uses a half-open range, just like it's customary for C++ loops, @mch.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt you are right, so it is `for i in range(0, 6):`

Comment: @Damien, yes how will you translate for(int i = 0; i!= 6; i++) in python ?
''''''

Comment: @Artashes I am not a Python expert, but your C++ code is equivalent to `for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)`. Therefore, I guess something like `for i in range(6):`. Maybe your C++ code doest not do what you are thinking it does

Comment: @Artashes I know C++ and I saw that your initial C++ code can be greatly simplified, at least assuming that this code is effectively doing what you want. You did not explain what this code is supposed to do. My first comment on C++ is correct, what not giving it? And I don't need to be a Python expert to know the Python translation of the simplified C++ code. So, what is the problem?

Comment: dear @damien this is not the place to debate, your for loop suggerstion is NOT the équivaent of the one I poste.

Comment: Maybe it would be best to post a full program, which prints messages, and demonstrate which output you are trying to get. You can [edit] your post if you want to clarify it. However, you got your answer, so do it only if you care about whoever will read this in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest Pythonic articulation is

```py
for i in range(11):
    if i == 6:
        continue
    ... stuff happens ...
```

Comment: This is exactly how I've done, I was juste curious if there exist one-line simple way as in C++

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805914/discontinuous-slice-in-python-list for some creative variations.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ a loop like

```
for (a; b; c)
   d;
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    a;
    while (b)
    {
        d;
        c;
    }
}
```

If you first translate your `for` loop to its corresponding `while` loop, then you could translate that `while` loop to Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to express the idea "do something for numbers from 0 to 10, except 6", the correct C++ code for it cannot be a simple for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    if (i != 6)
    {
        ... // do the stuff
    }
}
```

You can translate it literally to Python (see [answer by tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64445044/509868)) or make a real one-liner, like so:

Create a list of numbers for which you want to run the stuff: `[x for x in range(11) if x != 6]`. Then iterate on it:

```
for i in [x for x in range(11) if x != 6]:
    ... # do the stuff
```

From code readability standpoint, the solution with `if` or `continue` may be better than this one.

Comment: Well, try it in C++ and you will see my friend :)

But thanks for trying to help me with Python!